# ibuffer hide columns

Tags: ibuffer

How do you hide columns when inside the ibuffer window?

I don't want to see

`Size`
`Mode`
`Name`

Sometimes I just want to see only the column `Filename/Process`

What I tried:  googled `ibuffer hide columns`

Answer (score 3):

You can modify the variable *ibuffer-formats*:

```
 (setq ibuffer-format-save ibuffer-formats)
 (setq ibuffer-formats (append ibuffer-formats '((mark " " filename-and-process))))
```

After this, the backtick character (which runs *ibuffer-switch-format*) forces redisplay and cycles through the formats specified.  In my emacs, after running the above, there are now three formats in that cycle.

Comment: FWIW, I recommend including `mark` in every format, i.e. `(mark " " filename-and-process)` or similar, to reduce the risk of accidental mishaps.