# ibuffer hide beginning of lines

Tags: osx, regular-expressions, ibuffer, filtering

When I press `C-x C-b` I get ibuffer (installed as part of prelude I think)

I like to press backtick and get the `Filename/Process` displayed.
Another SE answer helped me with that. ([ibuffer hide columns](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/37229/ibuffer-hide-columns))

I have about a dozen files open, but my work happens in a deeply nested directory. So my ibuffer display is overflowing with all the parent folders information

`~/Work/Project/subjproject/submodule/foo/baa/etc/something/the_file_im_editing.pl`

Nowadays I'm exclusively working inside the `~/Work/Project/subjproject/submodule/` folder. So I buffer don't need to tell me that. It's wasted space to display that.

What can I do about this?

Answer (score 2):

I can think of three ways of handling this.

One would be to add a new column type to ibuffer.

A second (which would be system-wide) would be to define a directory alias in `directory-mode-alist`.  Playing with this, the alias needs to start with "/":

```el
(setq directory-abbrev-alist 
      '(("/home/realraptor/Work/Project/subjproject/submodule/foo/baa"
         . "/$PROJECT")))
```

Note that in this case, my experiments show that the alias needs a leading slash.  This only affects new buffers: filenames of existing file-visiting buffers are not affected.

A third (which would be confined to ibuffer mode) would be to define a directory alias in `ibuffer-directory-abbrev-alist`

```el
(setq ibuffer-directory-abbrev-alist 
      '(("/home/realraptor/Work/Project/subjproject/submodule/foo/baa"
         . "$PROJECT")))
```

This doesn't need the leading slash, and takes effect immediately.

Comment: The docstring of `directory-abbrev-alist` explains the need for the leading slash, as well as some other finer points about permitted values.